# How to get SPFieldChoice values using rest api SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest

I have a choice field in my list. I can get it values using server object model by following way

```
List<string> fieldList;

SPList spList = spWeb.Lists[listName];

SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)spList.Fields[fieldName];

fieldList = new List<string>();

foreach (string str in field.Choices){

             fieldList.Add(str);
         }
```

Now I need it badly using rest api. Is it possible using rest api?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have solved my problem following way

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "host url"+"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Choice Field Name'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results[0].Choices.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }

    });
```

Comment: What is EntityPropertyName here?

Comment: That is part of the filter. Substitute your field name for 'Choice Field Name'. For example, if your field is Category, your code would read ?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Category'.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code for retrieving choices of choice field

```
function getFieldChoices(fieldName, listName) {
var dfd = $.Deferred();
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));

var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('#mylist')/fields?@target='" + hostweburl + "'&$select=Choices&$filter=Title eq  '#myfield'";
var url = urlTemplate.replace("#mylist", listName).replace("#myfield", fieldName);

$.ajax({
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        var result = data.d.results[0].Choices.results;
        var i = result.length;
        dfd.resolve(result);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        dfd.reject(err);
    }
});
return dfd;
```

}

Source http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.in/2013/10/sharepoint-2013-rest-code-tips.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in React. A slight change in the call structure, but easily altered to the ajax call.

I have a SharePoint Picture Library (but a normal list works the same way). One of the columns is a Choice list of locations, e.g. "Perth", "Melbourne", etc. By using the following query I get an object back of all fields in the Picture library. e.g.

```
 let response: SPHttpClientResponse = await this.props.Context.spHttpClient
 .get(
  this.props.Domain + 
  this.props.Path + 
  this.props.ParentSiteName + 
  `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('` + 
  this.props.SPListNames.Floorplans + 
  `')/fields?$filter=InternalName eq 'Location'`,
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1
);

const Response = await response.json();

console.log('Response');
console.log(Response);
```

The key part of the query was: 
this.props.Domain + this.props.Path + this.props.ParentSiteName +  `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('` + this.props.SPListNames.Floorplans + `')/fields?$filter=InternalName eq 'Location'`

Which is: 
https://*sharepointtenantname.sharepoint.com*/sites/*name*/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/fields?$filter=InternalName eq 'Location'

Where *InternalName* is the attribute of the response object I get back from the SharePoint call that I want to filter on using my text 'Location'. If you are unsure of what to filter on, do a test call to this api to see the object that is returned and built the call based on your needs from that: 
https://*sharepointtenantname.sharepoint.com*/sites/*name*/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/fields

In the result, the object has a Choices attribute, which is an array of strings with all the choices I am interested in. I can use this to complete my task.