# How to get choice field choices using REST Api in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

I have a choice field **Status** with choice values Approved,Rejected and Hold.
How do I retrieve these choices using REST Api?

PFB the code:

```
$.ajax({
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Questions')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Status'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results[0].Choices.results);

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }

    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the choice values from `listdata.svc` you need to make a request against the correct `EntitySet`...

You can think of an `EntitySet` as any list that `listdata.svc` has access to -- this includes choice field choices.

Choice field EntitySets will typically have an endpoint name that looks like:

```
<ListName><ChoiceFieldName>
```

So if I have a list called `MyList` which has a choice field called `MyChoiceField`, then a call to the entity set name that can be accessed by `listdata.svc` would be have an endpoint of:

```
_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyListMyChoiceField
```

To find the precise name of the `EntitySet` you should be looking for, make a call to the top level endpoint `listdata.svc` in the site you're interested in.

Use something like:

```
$.getJSON('../_vti_bin/listdata.svc').then(function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

In your browser dev tools console, expand the result object. The results should be alphabetical by default, find your list name then below it you should see some more choices for choice fields within that specific list.

When you locate the correct endpoint name, just make a call to that `EntitySet` name like:

```
$.getJSON('../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyListMyChoiceField')
    .then(function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

The results to the call against the choice field endpoint will give you a `results` object which is an Array of objects representing the available choices for that field. You can access the values of the choices by using `data.d.results[i].Value` in the callback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time but am very new to rest api so i am not able to understand the whole thing that you have explained....Is it possible for you to re-edit my code with the right answer?

Comment: Better please refer this links: [Link1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/18defe52-d211-4720-993b-5e6197457e20/how-to-get-choice-fields-values-using-rest-api-or-jsom?forum=sharepointdevelopment), [Link2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/127869/how-to-get-spfieldchoice-values-using-rest-api-sharepoint-2013/127872), [Link3](https://atishdipongkor.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/how-to-get-spfieldchoice-values-using-rest-api-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 2):

Refer below code. This will work for you.

(Note: Here `choiceCol` is the name of my choice field. You will have to change it accordingly).

```
var url = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Questions')/items?$select=choiceCol";

getItems(url).then(getItemsSuccess, getItemsFail);

function getItems(url){
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}

function getItemsSuccess(data){
    var result = data.d.results; // set value of result variable 
    $.each(result, function(key, value){
        console.log(value.choiceCol);   // access the choice field value
    });
}

function getItemsFail(err){
    // error callback
    debugger;
}
```