# Google Chart API : Pie chart not working with Choice Columns

Tags: google-chart

I had problemns to create google charts in SharePoint and the answer of Ankitkumar Malde ([Google Chart API : Pie chart not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/237159/google-chart-api-pie-chart-not-working/248464#248464)) finally helped me!

Theres only one **problem**: it doesnt work if the column type is a **choice (checkboxes) column** (then no chart appears).

Is there a trick to make this work too?
Could someone modify his code?
Thanks a lot!

The code is:

```
<div id="piechart" style="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       var tempArray = [];
       var chartObj = [['status', 'Number']];

AjaxCall(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('test list2')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Orbit'", function(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results[0].Choices.results, function(index, value) {
        if (0 > tempArray.indexOf(value["Orbit"])) {
            tempArray.push(value["Orbit"]);
            chartObj.push([value["Orbit"], 1])
        } else {
            chartObj[tempArray.indexOf(value["Orbit"]) + 1][1] += 1;
        }
    });
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartObj);
        var options = {
            title: 'test title',
            is3D: 'true'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
});
});
function AjaxCall(url, success) {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: success,
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        alert('Something Went Wrong');
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
            <div id="piechart" style="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
            <script type="text/javaScript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var tempArray = [];
                    var chartObj = [['status', 'Number']];

                    AjaxCall(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('IncidentsReports')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Status'", function (data) {
                        $.each(data.d.results[0].Choices.results, function (index, value) {
                            if (0 > tempArray.indexOf(value)) {
                                tempArray.push(value);
                                chartObj.push([value, 1])
                            } else {
                                chartObj[tempArray.indexOf(value) + 1][1] += 1;
                            }
                        });
                        google.charts.load('current', {
                            'packages': ['corechart']
                        });
                        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartObj);
                            var options = {
                                title: 'test title',
                                is3D: 'true'
                            };
                            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
                            chart.draw(data, options);
                        });
                    });
                });
                function AjaxCall(url, success) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        },
                        success: success,
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                            alert('Something Went Wrong');
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
```

[image]

Comment: i used list from my root site so i used siteabsoluteurl you can change to webabsoluteurl

Comment: Thanks. I finally had time to test it. The problem with the code is that the charts created have a equal distribution - which is not the case in my list (like in your screenshot: 20% - 20% - 20% - 20% - 20%) Do you know the reason?